# With Express after authentication what is safer "redirect or render"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bcrypt

Should i redirect or render the page? What is the best practice for authentication.

```
var User = require('models/user.js');
        User.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password)
            .then(function(error, user){
                //IF SUCCES AND NO ERROR
                res.redirect('/profile');
                //OR
                res.render('profile.pug');
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your route you should do:

When everything is ok (no errors):

```
return res.render('view',{
    param1:param2
});
```

When error appears:

```
req.flash('error', error.message); // If you are using flash
return res.redirect('back');      // It will redirect user back
                                 // and display some error message
```

If you are going to write middleware for authentication:

```
middlewareObj.isAuthenticated = function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    } else {
        return res.redirect('/signin'); // Or status code
    }
};
```